# GCP Queries per day shows 0% for "Current usage" and for "7 days peak"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP to monitor the number of API calls of Google Books API. It used to work fine but now it shows zero for both "Current usage" and for "7 days peak".

This of course can't be correct as the Books API works perfectly fine (I can see that in Analytics tools).

The Browser points to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=books.googleapis.com&authuser=0&project=api-project-<my_project_number>

Any idea what could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are some [known errors](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#quota_errors) on quotas APIs that you can identified but also you can [Monitoring and alerting on quota metrics](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#monitoring_quota_metrics).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is not included in the known errors. I think it's a glitch specific to my account. I'm currently in touch with Google to resolve it...